# How to get same functionality without repeating the same plugin in webpack

Tags: webpack, concatenation, frontend

Since I have many files to concatenate in my application I don't want to end up writing the same plugin again and again. my approach is to concatenate individual files related to the specific module in my app. Please Advise.

```
const ConcatPlugin = require('webpack-concat-plugin');

new ConcatPlugin({
    useHash: true, // md5 file
    sourceMap: true, // generate sourceMap
    options: {
        process: function(src, filepath) {
            src = src.replace('"use strict";','');
            return '$(function () {\n' + src + '\n});';
        }
    },
    fileName: 'js/react/_react.es6.do-not-edit.js',
    filesToConcat: [
        './js/react/promises.js',
        './js/react/comps.js',
        './js/react/press-release-component.js'
    ]
}),
new ConcatPlugin({
    useHash: true, // md5 file
    sourceMap: true, // generate sourceMap
    options: {
        process: function(src, filepath) {
            src = src.replace('"use strict";','');
            return '$(function () {\n' + src + '\n});';
        }
    },
    fileName: globalPath.theme + '/js/script.min.js',
    filesToConcat: [
        './js/languages.min.js',
        './js/_script.min.do-not-edit.js',
        './js/_react.es5.min.do-not-edit.js'
    ]
}),
new ConcatPlugin({
    useHash: true, // md5 file
    sourceMap: true, // generate sourceMap
    options: {
        process: function(src, filepath) {
            src = src.replace('"use strict";','');
            return '$(function () {\n' + src + '\n});';
        }
    },
    fileName: globalPath.theme + '/js/script.js',
    filesToConcat: [
        './js/script.js',
        './js/_react.es5.do-not-edit.js'
    ]
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that can take an array of file groups, which are just the files to concat. Iterate through those to create plugin instances and return the array of plugin instances.  You may also need to use the spread operator.

```
let appFileGroups = [
        [
          './js/script.js',
          './js/_react.es5.do-not-edit.js'
        ],
        [
          './js/script.js',
          './js/_react.es5.do-not-edit.js'
        ],
    ];



function concatFileGroups(fileGroups) {
   return fileGroups.map(fileGroup => {
     new ConcatPlugin({
         useHash: true, // md5 file
         sourceMap: true, // generate sourceMap
         options: {
             process: function(src, filepath) {
                 src = src.replace('"use strict";','');
                 return '$(function () {\n' + src + '\n});';
             }
         },
         fileName: globalPath.theme + '/js/script.js',
         filesToConcat: fileGroup 
      })
   }
}
```

In webpack config:

```
  plugins : [
     concatFileGroups(appFileGroups),
     // if that doesnt work try this
     //...concatFileGroups(appFileGroups),
     // remaining plugins
```

Comment: I resolved that and than I see arguments[i].apply is not a function

Comment: try  `...concatFileGroups(appFileGroups),`

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and responding. Cheers!

Comment: sorry I didn't login to SO, I used a copy-webpack-plugin to achieve same. Thanks for the response.